# Named queries in Appfuse

Tags: appfuse

I used to have named query methods in Repository interface without an implementation (like findByMember(Member m)). Or interface methods with @Query annotation, again without implementation.

In Appfuse, Repository interfaces have implementation (like RoleDaoHimernate), so I have to write implementations.

Could you tell me way to avoid making implementations and to write only named queries and annotated queries?

Comment: We plan to integrate Spring Data in the next release - I believe that's what you're looking for. http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Roadmap

Comment: Thanks for your post, Matt. Thanks for the great AppFuse and good lock to the project.